# How to change initial ActiveDirectory password with JAVA WebApplication?

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

Currently I have developed a Java WebApplication to offer the ability to change AD-controlled passwords. The WebApplication uses LDAP access to do this. The users need to authenticate and then their password is changed bei a "LdapContext.modifyAttributes()"-method.

Now I experienced that this does not work for users with an initial password. Initial password means the flag "pwdLastSet" is set to require password change by next logon.

This is, how it works now.

```
prop.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
prop.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldaps://my.active.directory.com:636");
prop.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
prop.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL,"ADSecurityProtocol");
prop.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,this.userid);
prop.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS,password);
ldapContext = new InitialLdapContext(prop, null); 

<...snip...>

ModificationItem[] mods = new ModificationItem[2];
String oldQuotedPassword = "\"" + oldPassword + "\"";
byte[] oldUnicodePassword = oldQuotedPassword.getBytes("UTF-16LE");
String newQuotedPassword = "\"" + newPassword1 + "\"";
byte[] newUnicodePassword = newQuotedPassword.getBytes("UTF-16LE");

mods[0] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REMOVE_ATTRIBUTE,
new BasicAttribute("unicodePwd", oldUnicodePassword));
mods[1] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.ADD_ATTRIBUTE,
new BasicAttribute("unicodePwd", newUnicodePassword));
ldapContext.modifyAttributes(userDN, mods);
```

I'm looking for an idea how to enable users to change their password especially when they are required to do so. I found some hints that Kerberos might be required - but I almost don't know anything about Kerberos.

Any help is appreciated.

Ulrich

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite get the question. The code pasted doesn't work when pwdLastSet is set ? or you looking for an idea to let the users know that they have to change their pwd ?

If code isn't working, have you tried DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE ?

If you needed a way to let users know, just catch the exception and show a error msg on the ui.

Comment: First: I got the information that forcing the user to change his password is indicated by the attribute pwdLastSet from searching through the internet - I don't know this for sure.

Comment: My coding shows two blocks - the "bind" and the "password change". When the "Password Change Required" is set the bind fails with error: Invalid logon credentials: '[LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 773
This means I can#

Comment: This means I cant even do a logon. 
I didn't try to modify "pwdLastSet" - I would have needed administrative authority. And I'm not sure whether modifying this flag will help.
But anyway: My question is "How can I manage let the user with the initial password set to allow to change it. My posting shows how it works works works a regular password.
This means I have also a second question: Will it help to change "pwdLastSet" to "-1" to allow for login (and changing the password then).

Comment: And the suggested method "DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE" also needs administrative authority. The program was meant to allow the users to change their password by themselves - authenticating with their own password.

Comment: @Ulrich Did you find a solution on this? I am working with a commercial product (Java based which uses using Apache LDAP API) and am trying the same thing and facing the same issues. The pwdLastSet returns me INVALID_CREDENTIALS and cannot proceed with reset/set password.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the Apache LDAP API, it seems easier than pure JNDI.

I did a blog post about it, but using AWS Simple AD implementation. I may be useful:
http://blog.techutils.space/2016/02/changing-samba4-aws-simple-ad-user.html